# Copy/Pasting DOCTYPE Tag Into Vi Document

Tags: xml, copy-paste, vi, putty, doctype

I am using PuTTy to remote into a Unix box (*HP-UX*) and require to copy/paste *XSD* Schema contents into files manually (no *SCP* or *sftp* allowed unfortunately).

What I do is first is to unset the auto indenting behavior of *Vi* (`:set noautoindent`), however, when I copy/paste the content, I notice that the following snippet,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
...
```

Is copied as following:

```
CTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
...
```

Which makes me to manually copy the prolog line and type `<!DO` to the beginning of `DOCTYPE` line. Everything else gets copied properly. Is there a reason why copy/pasting into *Vi* omits these first two lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably forgot going into `i`nsert mode first. Dissecting your input,

- `<` de-indent from here to ...

  - `?` search backwards to ...

    - `xml version="1.0"?>` `<Return>`

    (which probably doesn't find anything, hence stays in place)

  (hence de-indent current line by 1 — which does nothing as it's empty)
- `<` de-indent from here to ...

  - `!` (does nothing)
- `D` delete current line (empty, does *almost* nothing)
- `O` go into insert mode in *a new line above the current*
  (thereby inverting the deletion of the empty line)

  - `CTYPE…` (and the rest of the text appears as expected)